# How to make Paramiko use PowerShell by default?

Tags: python, powershell, ssh, cmd, paramiko

I'm SSHing to a Windows machine with `Paramiko` and I'm stressed out by how hard it is to write a command because:

- `exec_command` runs in `cmd` prompt console, which has limited functionality so I need PowerShell, meaning I should prefix the command with `pwsh -c "the command"`
- However, `cmd` prompt doesn't support multi-line nor multiple commands naturally, so I need to stick in  caret `^`s and `&&`s in the command.
- ***Inside*** the command I'm calling Python with `python -c 'print("hello")\nprint("world")'`, however I'm already using `"` for `pwsh -c "the command"` meaning I need to escape it with backticks `` `" ``.

This is fiendishly complex and ugly, the code is a mess, it's Python and PowerShell and cmd prompt special characters intertwined at once. I'm almost 100% sure I'm missing something and there is an easier way to do it hence I'm asking whether Paramiko can run do `exec_command` in PowerShell by default.

Comment: Technically, nested double quotes would require escaping for cmd.exe to pass, which means those should be escaped using backward slashes, i.e. ```pwsh -c "python -c 'print(\"hello\")\nprint(\"world\")'"```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client (Paramiko) has no control over how the command is interpreted. It's about *the server*.

Windows Win32-OpenSSH definitely [can use PowerShell as the default shell](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/DefaultShell).

Comment: Microsoft should just cull cmd, its simply lame and vastly inferior.